# Connection refused when trying to SSH. But port 22 is not blocked. Pings work

Tags: ssh, centos, docker

Connection refused when trying to SSH.  But port 22 is not blocked. Pings work.
I'm running CentOS 7 VMs and open source Docker.  I want to SSH to Docker containers from other VMs or other Docker containers.  How do I do this?

I can SSH from the Docker containers to their shared host VM.  I cannot SSH into the Docker containers from the host VM because of an error "Connection refused."  I cannot SSH to the Docker containers from the containers themselves because of "connection refused."  nmap results show that ports 1 through 1000 are closed but not filtered on each container.  I tested against the IP address in the result of a docker inspect command.

I can ping the Docker containers from each other using their IP addresses.  sftp between the containers fails because of "connection refused."  Given that there is no firewall rule on port 22, what is causing this "connection refused" problem?

If you are not familiar with Docker, can you provide me with possible root causes given that nmap rules out port blockage?  Pings work.  Docker containers function VERY similarly to Linux servers.

Comment: This looks like a Docker network config issue, and not a security issue - migrating.

Comment: ... are the containers running an SSH server?

Answer (score 1):

Since `nmap` says ports 1 through 1000 are closed (and in particular, port 22 is closed), you probably don't have an `sshd` running inside the container. Some options:

- Modify your `Dockerfile` so `sshd` does get started.
- Enter your container (e.g., `docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash`) and start `sshd` yourself.

If you only really wanted `sshd` to be able to get a shell inside your container, the `docker exec` command above might be all you really need anyway.

Comment: When I try to start sshd, I get "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted."  Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific about what `Dockerfile` you're using and what commands you're running.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the docker containers are not running sshd.  You can get a shell in a running container like this (which might solve the real problem you are trying to solve):

```
docker exec -it bash
```